# Dual booting Windows 10 Insider (Upgrading frequently) and Ubuntu

Tags: dual-boot, grub2

Now that the Fast ring of Insider has builds every few weeks, if I upgrade using Windows Update to another build, I'll lose GRUB.
Now is that all? If I upgrade, I just need to restore grub and I'll have both builds? Windows Insider won't have any problems right?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have an EFI based installation setup you don't even have to restore GRUB
because GRUB is installed to a separate folder (Ubuntu) within the EFI partition.

You can use `bcdedit` ( Windows command line tool ) to update the Windows BCDstore.
Then boot into BIOS setup and switch the default OS to boot from Windows to Ubuntu.

When booting your machine, you now can select which OS you want to boot from GRUB menu.
Anyway, to answer your main question : No, it will not hurt Windows Insider Preview installation.

Note: Only in case your installation setup is mbr based (legacy BIOS) you  have to reinstall GRUB.

Comment: No it's not a EFI based installation, using MBR. So I have to use ubuntu live cd to restore ubuntu after a insider upgrade?

Edit: Did not see your edit. I guess I can safely install Ubuntu now. Thanks for the help! Cheers.